# Excel Solver exclude where price is zero

Tags: excel, solver

I am using the basic solver in MS Excel to solve a Simplex LP to minimize the total cost of product 1-3 based on allocations from supplier A-C. My issue is that since not all suppliers provide each product, so when I set the LP, it just sets allocations to the supplier no price, which treats it as cost "$0".

```
 Price
           SupplierA SupplierB SupplierC
 Product1  $1.50     $2.00
 Product2  $2.00               $1.00
 Product3            $2.50     $1.50
```

Is there a constraint I can set to prevent solver from allocating where price is zero? I thought about setting the blanks to 999999 but that would make the table look odd. I also tried setting null prices instead of blanks but that caused an error with the optimizer. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In the total cost formula, I just used =if(price = "", 999999999 * allocation, price * allocation)